# How can I resolve an issue with [civicrm.files] following an update to 5.29

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, upgrade

Just updated my Civi 5.25 install running with Wordpress on a Cloudron LAMP stack to 5.29. Now Civi is generating lots of alerts about unknown extensions - it looks like it can't find my extension files, and in the Civi log I'm seeing lots of warnings stating "[warning] The system has data from both old+new conventions. Please use civicrm.settings.php to set civicrm.files explicitly."

How do I set civicrm.files explicitly in civicrm.settings.php?

I'm guessing these two issues are linked, and that if I can set civicrm.files explicitly then Civi will be able to find my extension files.

Answer (score 1):

The information provided in the docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/paths/
explains how to set civicrm.files in the civicrm.settings.php file.